# Should I use a single SSL certificate for example.com and www.example.com?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, https, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website (hosted by Amazon S3) which redirects `example.com` to `www.example.com`. I am setting up an Amazon CloudFront distribution for this website, and would like the same redirection to work for HTTPS. I believe I therefore need to secure both `example.com` and `www.example.com`.

I will be using free SSL certificates generated by AWS Certificate Manager. My first instinct is to create one certificate for each of `example.com` and `www.example.com`. However, are there any advantages to putting both `example.com` and `www.example.com` (or even `example.com` and `*.example.com`) on a single certificate?

Answer (score 4):

It's easier to maintain if you have one certificate, and there are no real downsides. You can put as many unrelated domains as you like on a certificate, so putting the www subdomain on seems fairly reasonable. Just use one certificate IMHO.

Comment: Thanks. Would you recommend adding just the `www` subdomain, or would you prefer a wildcard certificate (adding `*.example.com`)? Might the latter further ease maintenance, even though no other subdomains are currently being used (or planned for the near future)?

Comment: If wildcard is easy I suggest you do that.

Comment: @user200783 If you have no plans to add more subdomains, then a wildcard cert would just be unnecessary expense.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Certificates from AWS Certificate Manager [are free](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/#billing). This [includes wildcard certificates](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/#certificates). So, a certificate for `example.com` and `*.example.com` would cost no more than one for `example.com` and `www.example.com`. In this case, is there any reason to prefer the latter certificate over the wildcard one?

Comment: No reason comes to mind, in the context of ACM.

Answer (score 0):

These two domains ideally considered as one. So they do not need two various certificates.

At present, most of SSL certificates (Comodo, RapidSSL) support both **WWW** and **Non-WWW** version of domain name. So both version of your domain name `example.com` and `www.example.com` will be supported by HTTPS. Therefor you will have to set 301 redirection of example.com to www.example.com, so anyone types `example.com` then browser will redirect users to `www.example.com`